# How do I find the RGB representation of a Color object?

Tags: java

How do I convert say, yellow (as a Color object), to RGB representation?

```
Color color = Color.YELLOW;
// how to print (r,y,b) of color?
```

I can find the actual number representations online but I'm curious about the process of actually converting from one to another.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by the "actual number representation"?

Comment: You google and find a large number of websites with color swatches and their RGB values.

Comment: @Code-Guru oh by that I mean I looked online to find common RGB numbers for colors. So at this point, I'm just curious as to how to convert any given color to RGB

Comment: "Yellow" is a word. What exactly do you expect to be the input?

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you are asking. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Comment: @Code-Guru yea the question I was given is: define the following colors in terms of RGB, e.g. Blue = Color(0,0,255). And then I'm given several other colors such as white, yellow, purple.

Comment: I prefer to take a screen shot and paste it into paint. Then use the sucker tool and edit colors. That gives me the RGB value so I can use it in my program

Comment: @Robert Snyder it's odd because I was given this in a beginner's java class with no direction as to how to accomplish this

Comment: It sounds like [you have asked the wrong question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242)

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question fully but JColorChooser is a nice tool

Comment: Perhaps your Java teacher is trying to give you a crash course in Color Theory. In additive colors, red, green, and blue are the primary colors while yellow, cyan, and magenta are the secondary colors. A quick google search will tell you which primary colors are mixed to make each of the secondary colors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`getBlue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getBlue%28%29), [`getGreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getGreen%28%29), and [`getRed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed%28%29).

```
Color yellow = Color.YELLOW;
System.out.printf("red: %d, green: %d, blue: %d",
        yellow.getRed(), yellow.getGreen(), yellow.getBlue());
```

And if you wish to extract the alpha channel as well, you can use [`getAlpha()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getAlpha%28%29).

Comment: Why do I get an error when trying to print this? "The method print(int) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments.."

Comment: @xheyhenry My mistake, I used `println` instead of `printf` with a formatted string. Edited to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the exact color that you want. I would play around with different numbers and gain an understanding for how the colors work. They go from dark to light, where dark is 0 and light is 255, so (255,255,255) is white and (0,0,0) is black. To get a yellowish color, play around with a medium red value and equal green and blue values that are fairly high.

Comment: I understand how the whole system works, but if I were to give you the color turquoise and asked you to convert that to RGB, how would you do it?

Comment: @xheyhenry "turquoise" does not uniquely identify a color. There is no one RGB value which "is" turquoise. Any such imprecise mapping is simply a semi-arbitrary table.

Comment: I would create a murky blueish color, with red being fairly low and green and blue being fairly high.

Comment: If by "yellowish", the OP meant "a light turquoise colour", this would be a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the hex string that you can use in HTML.  I would do it like this.

```
public String toRgb(Color arg){
    return String.format("%02X%02X%02X", arg.getRed(), arg.getGreen(), arg.getBlue());
}
```